# How to specify a part of code to run in a particular thread in a multithreaded environment in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, python-multithreading, distributed-system

How to achieve something like:

```py
def call_me():
   # doing some stuff which requires distributed locking

def i_am_calling():
   # other logic
   call_me()
   # other logic
```

This code runs in a multithreaded environment. How can I make it something like, only a single thread from the thread pool has responsibility to run `call_me()` part of the `i_am_calling()`?

Comment: did you read about [Lock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects), and [Semaphore](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects)? At the end of page you can see also example using `with`

Comment: Writing code that behaves differently depending on the identity of the thread that calls it seems like a Bad Idea. Writing code that behaves differently depending on the identity of the thread-pool worker that calls it seems like a _spectacularly_ Bad Idea. What is your reason for wanting to do that? (Or, did I completely misunderstand what it is that you want to do?)

Comment: @SolomonSlow call_me() task is something which will require a distributed lock (using redis here) and this function is to be scheduled for every say 1 hour. So I don't want that all the threads try to acquire a lock after 1 hour. Just one thread doing this scheduled job.

Comment: I don't know much about Python's libraries, but thread pools that I have worked with  do not typically guarantee anything about the identity of their worker threads. In particular, some thread pool implementations kill off worker threads during intervals of low demand, and create new workers when demand rises. Again, I don't know a lot about what's available in Python, but If I were writing a program that needed to do something once every hour, I would use some kind of a timer task for that or--worst case--a dedicated thread that loops, doing the thing, and then sleeping for an hour.

Comment: I am going with your worst case: a dedicated thread that loops, doing the thing, and then sleeping for an hour. Is it good for performance?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the exact requirement in hand and on the system architecture / solution. Accordingly, one of the approach can be based on [lock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects) to ensure that only one process does the locking at a time.

You can arrive on logic by trying usage of [apply_async](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) of the multiprocessing module that could enable invocation of a number of different functions (not of same type of function) with pool.apply_async.  It shall use only one process when that function is invoked only once, however you can bundle up tasks ahead and pass/submit these tasks to the various worker processes. There is also the pool.apply that submits a task to the pool , but it blocks until the function is completed or result is available. The equivalent of it is pool.apply_async(func, args, kwargs).get() based on get() or a callback function with pool.apply_async without get(). Also, it should be noted that pool.apply(f, args) ensures that only one of the workers of the pool will execute f(args).

You can also arrive on logic by trying of making a respective call in its own thread using [executor.submit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.submit) that is part of [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) which is a standard Python library . The asyncio can be coupled with concurrent.futures such that it can await functions executed in thread or process pools provided by concurrent.futures as highlighted in this [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executing-code-in-thread-or-process-pools).

If you would like to run a routine functionality at regular interval, then you can arrive on a logic based on [threading.timer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Timer).